# How to save and store the data in Azure SQL database using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I am seeking help in storing and saving data in Azure SQL Database. Could anyone please help me with how I can code in C# or the libraries required to do the same

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Could you give us more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

You can also use the following code, it's a simple .NET framework console project and all the needed assembly is added by default:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //define the connection string of azure database.
            var cnString = "Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";

            //define the insert sql command, here I insert data into the student table in azure db.
            string cmdText = @"insert into student
                   (name,age)
                   values(@name, @age)";


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "yang1");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", 20);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("completed***");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It can insert data successfully into azure database at my side. The screenshot as below:

[image]

---

The [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database-csharp) provides all the CURD operations. Follow this doc to fetch azure sql database connection string, and set firewall.

The needed assembly is **System.Data.dll**, which should be added by default when create a project in visual studio.

The sample code is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database-csharp#connect-to-sql-database-using-adonet). For save data, you can see this method `static string Build_3_Tsql_Inserts()` in this section [Methods that return T-SQL statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database-csharp#methods-that-return-t-sql-statements).

Comment: The table is already been created in Azure, i need to save it in Azure SQL table using C#

Comment: @sanjanajha, yes, just use the insert method Build_3_Tsql_Inserts(). Please try it.

Comment: @sanjanajha, the doc provides a completed example including insert data, you can pick up the code what you need, like insert method:)

Comment: Sure thank you i will try

Comment: @sanjanajha, I updated my post with a simple insert code, it works fine. You can refer to it, and modify as per your need:)

Comment: Thank you so much, will surely try and update here

Comment: The above is not allowing to connect to db

Comment: @sanjanajha, do you [Create a server-level IP firewall rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-first-database-csharp#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule).

Comment: yes, its working fine now. But is there a way to enter multiple records?

Comment: @sanjanajha, do you have any experience using c# with local MS SQL? if you know, it's exactly the same batch insert operation with azure sql and local ms sql. But if you don't know, please let me know, I will provide a sample to you:).

Comment: @sanjanajha, a simple way is that include the insert operation within a **for** or **foreach** code block.

Comment: @sanjanajha, if the post is helpful, could you accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to start with the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/) and try the course [`Provision an Azure SQL database to store application data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/provision-azure-sql-db/)

Answer (score 0):

Try working threw these. 
[A Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase)

[Another Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase)